# How to calculate total in a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-calculation

I have tried to do the calculation of the marks obtained and want it to display in a table. As in the javascript, the calculation that i have did is as below:

```
<script>
                        function kira1() {
                            var myeBook = document.getElementById('eBook').value;
                            var result = document.getElementById('result1');
                            var myResult = myeBook * 3;
                            result.value = myResult;
                        }
                        function kira2() {
                            var mybukuTeks = document.getElementById('bukuTeks').value;
                            var result = document.getElementById('result2');
                            var myResult = mybukuTeks * 3;
                            result.value = myResult;
                        }
                        function kira3() {
                            var mymodul = document.getElementById('modul').value;
                            var result = document.getElementById('result3');
                            var myResult = mymodul * 2;
                            result.value = myResult;
                        }
                        function kira4() {
                            var myjurnal = document.getElementById('jurnal').value;
                            var result = document.getElementById('result4');
                            var myResult = myjurnal * 2;
                            result.value = myResult;
                        }
                        function kira5() {
                            var myePembelajaran = document.getElementById('ePembelajaran').value;
                            var result = document.getElementById('result5');
                            var myResult = myePembelajaran * 1;
                            result.value = myResult;
                        }
                        function kira6() {
                            var myinovasi = document.getElementById('inovasi').value;
                            var result = document.getElementById('result6');
                            var myResult = myinovasi * 1;
                            result.value = myResult;
                        }
                        function kira7() {
                            var a = document.getElementById('result1').value;
                            var b = document.getElementById('result2').value;
                            var c = document.getElementById('result3').value;
                            var d = document.getElementById('result4').value;
                            var e = document.getElementById('result5').value;
                            var f = document.getElementById('result6').value;
                            var result = document.getElementById('jumlah_1A');
                            var myResult = a + b + c + d + e + f;
                            result.value = myResult;
                        }           
                    </script>
```

But when i tried to run it, the total is not displaying as i want it to.

This is the output:
[image]

The total should be display at the "Jumlah Skor 1A"

Comment: What is jumlah_1A element? Could you provide html of the page? May be you need to do result.innerHTML = myResult ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
document.getElementById('jumlah_1A').innerHTML
i.e. document.getelementbyid('idname').innerHTML
```

As per my understanding 'jumlah_1A' is a div not a Input box. so use .innerHTML instead of .value

W3school Link: 
    http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('result1').value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('result2').value);
var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('result3').value);
var d = parseInt(document.getElementById('result4').value);
var e = parseInt(document.getElementById('result5').value);
var f = parseInt(document.getElementById('result6').value);
```

Convert all to integer before adding the values.
if jumlah_1A element is not a textbox then do

```
result.innerHTML = myResult;
```